Android studio/ react native
I have a code, that asks a permissions for an Android storage. When i run it on emulator(pixel 8 pro) it works correctly, but when i build project as release version and install it on my own Galaxy A73, permissions permissions are not asked and are rejected by default. I can't figure out what the problem is.
The code:
import {request, PERMISSIONS} from 'react-native-permissions';
import {Button} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
    const ask = () => {
        request(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
    return (
        <Button title = "ask" style = {{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
        }} onPress = {() => ask()}>
        </Button>
    );
};

export default App;

I tried several libs, like AndroidPermissions, but it works same.

Are you sure that you haven't denied the permission at some point? Try to change it to "Ask every time". See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#dialog-visibility.
